# How do I create a macro to move the oldest 20 emails from the bottom of my inbox to another folder in outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook, automation

I'm trying to move the bottom 20 emails to another folder in Outlook to another folder where the macro runs. I'm able to move then when selected but I don't want to have to select 20 from the bottom (oldest) first. I'd like to automate this bit too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's what I have so far but it moves the most recent mail only, regardless of how the inbox is sorted:

```
Public Sub Move_Inbox_Emails()

Dim outApp As Object
Dim outNS As Object
Dim inboxFolder As Object
Dim destFolder As Object
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim inboxItems As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim inputNumber As String
Dim numberToMove As Integer



inputNumber = InputBox("Enter number of emails to move")
On Error Resume Next
numberToMove = CInt(inputNumber)
On Error GoTo 0
If numberToMove < 1 Then Exit Sub

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outNS = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxFolder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set destFolder = inboxFolder.Parent.Folders("Mobus")             'Test folder at same level as Inbox

'Sort Inbox items by Received Time

Set itemsCol = inboxFolder.Items
itemsCol.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False

'Loop through sorted items for the number entered by the user, up to the number of items in the Inbox

For i = inboxFolder.Items.Count To inboxFolder.Items.Count - numberToMove + 1 Step -1
    If inboxFolder.Items(i).Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then
        Set outEmail = inboxFolder.Items(i)
        'Debug.Print outEmail.ReceivedTime, outEmail.subject
        outEmail.Move destFolder
        End If
Next
End Sub
```

I've solved this now with some ideas from the commentors, thanks very much. This code now prompts for how many to move and takes them from the oldest first:

```
Public Sub Move_Inbox_Emails_From_Excel()

Dim outApp As Object
Dim outNS As Object
Dim inboxFolder As Object
Dim destFolder As Object
Dim outEmail As Object
Dim inboxItems As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim inputNumber As String
Dim numberToMove As Integer

inputNumber = InputBox("Enter number of emails to move")
On Error Resume Next
numberToMove = CInt(inputNumber)
On Error GoTo 0
If numberToMove < 1 Then Exit Sub

Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set outNS = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxFolder = outNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set destFolder = inboxFolder.Parent.Folders("Mobus")             'Test folder at same level as Inbox

'Sort Inbox items by Received Time

Set inboxItems = inboxFolder.Items
'inboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False     'ascending order (oldest first)
inboxItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True      'descending order (newest first)

'Loop through sorted items for the number entered by the user, up to the number of items in the Inbox

For i = inboxFolder.Items.Count To inboxFolder.Items.Count - numberToMove + 1 Step -1
    Set outEmail = inboxItems(i)
    'Debug.Print i, outEmail.Subject
    outEmail.Move destFolder
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What have you started, can we see your code and we will help you modify it

Comment: The order of the items in the folder is whatever it was before. The order is not reliable, otherwise you could pick the first 20 or last 20. "Sort only affects the order of items in a collection. It does not affect the order of items in an explorer view." This example demonstrates sorting a collection of items (myItems) in myFolder. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866960.aspx     Set myItems = myFolder.Items /     myItems.Sort "[DueDate]", False Once sorted the collection (myItems), not the folder items (myFolder.Items), is used in the For loop.  For Each myItem In myItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the Items collection by ReceivedTime property, loop though the last 20 items (use a down loop - step -1) and move the items.

Comment: Not sure this works in this code. I've tried adding the line in to sort but it still picked the newest first. Thanks.

Comment: You could just take 20 from the other end but do not to that. It is not reliable. As indicated, sort a collection not the folder. Set itemsCol = inboxFolder.Items  / itemsCol.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False or True whichever way you need it to be. Again you could take 20 from either end of itemsCol but now it would be consistent.

Comment: I've updated the OP to show what I have now since the comments, but still no joy. No matter how it's sorted, it still gives the most recently received emails

Comment: You need to use the itemsCol variable instead of using inboxFolder.Items in the loop.

Comment: Solved - Added solution above

Comment: Also change the "for" line to use the itemsCol variable. Please mark the reply as answer if it answers your question.